# Cant set Triggers to Toggle Button

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, triggers

I can't attach triggers to a toggle button

1. In the first version, I get an error that the style is already redefined
2. In the second version with triggers, I get an error that property
   Command - The member "Command" is not recognized or is not accessible.

This is Button

```xml
<ToggleButton
               Name="ToggleButton_Record"
               IsChecked="False"
               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionToggleButton}"
               ToolTip="Записать">

               <materialDesign:PackIcon
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="OrangeRed"
                    Kind="Record" />

</ToggleButton>
```

This is 1st variant

```xml
 <ToggleButton.Style>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StartRecordCommand}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                                  <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StopRecordCommand}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
 </ToggleButton.Style>
```

2nd variant with triggers

```xml
 <ToggleButton.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StartRecordCommand}" />
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StopRecordCommand}" />
           </Trigger>
</ToggleButton.Triggers>
```

Yes I know that in 1st variant I just remove style in button and its starting works, but I need this style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 1st Variant. **Remove the Style="{..}"**. and then, in the Style you defined, add the `BasedOn`.

```
<ToggleButton
               Name="ToggleButton_Record"
               IsChecked="False"
               ToolTip="Записать">

              <ToggleButton.Style>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionToggleButton}">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StartRecordCommand}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                                  <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding StopRecordCommand}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
              </ToggleButton.Style>


               <materialDesign:PackIcon
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="OrangeRed"
                    Kind="Record" />

</ToggleButton>
```